Upgrade Magento version without affecting other paid community modules
Current Magento v2.4.5-p1.
Process Magento version to 2.4.5-p7 upgrade by following process give on below link.
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/implementation/perform-upgrade

Switch to maintenance mode to prevent access to your store during the upgrade process
 bin/magento maintenance:enable


Starting the upgrade process while asynchronous processes, such as message queue consumers, are running may cause data corruption. To prevent data corruption, disable all cron jobs.
bin/magento cron:remove

Start all message queue consumers manually to ensure all messages are consumed.
bin/magento cron:run --group=consumers

Create a backup of the composer.json file.
cp composer.json composer.json.bak

Add or remove specific packages based on your needs.
composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p7 --no-update

Run composer update
composer update




But at the same time it auto download all community paid module which was installed through composer.
How to restrict do not upgraded other community module just upgrade Magento.

Getting error when execute command #: compose install --lock [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException] The "--lock" option does not exist. composer.lock file already exist
